# Cypress: want to define methods as POM

Tags: cypress

I have only recently become involved with Cypress and have experience with Selenium. I know from Selenium that you outsource your elements and methods to separate classes via the Page Object Model and then access them in the test. So that if something changes, you only have to change the elements and methods once and not in every test.

Is that also possible with Cypress?

Example:
I want to store the `src` of an image in a method and return it as a return.
Here is the code:

```
get_main_image_slider_active_picture_src() {
    cy.get('.heroBanner.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active img')
    .should('have.attr','src')
    .then((imgSrc) => {
        const src = imgSrc;
    })
    return src;
}
```

Unfortunately, I have the feeling that this does not work as it does in Selenium.

How can i handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few SO questions on this topic, worth going over them.

Essentially the problem is PO methods work by returning values synchronously, but Cypress commands are asynchronous and you can't `await` them, you can only "chain" them.

This sequence is a chain,

```
cy.get('.heroBanner.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active img')
  .should('have.attr','src')
  .then(...
```

Each command produces a "subject", which is passed down the chain,

```
cy.get('.heroBanner.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active img')
    // subject === one or more <img> elements meeting the selector criteria
  .should('have.attr','src')
    // subject === the src attribute of the <img>
```

Finding the subject could be done synchronously, but `cy.get()` also retries in case the element is being fetched from an api, or is animating.

Simple pseudo-code is

```
while (not found and not timeout) {
  found = query the DOM for the selector
}
```

The while loop runs for an indeterminate time, so it's asynchronous. Also each step might fail if the element doesn't show up before the timeout.

So a PO method that uses Cypress commands can only return a Chainer, and can only be used like an asynchronous Cypress command (or custom command).

**Page object**

```
class HeroPage {

  get_main_image_slider_active_picture_src() {
    // here returning the final subject of this chain, wrapped as a chainer
    return cy.get('.heroBanner.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active img')
      .should('have.attr','src')
  }
}
```

**Test**

```
it('tests the picture page for kittens', () => {
  const heroPage = new HeroPage()
  heroPage.get_main_image_slider_active_picture_src()
    .should(src => src.includes('kittens'))              // chained subject
})
```

My opinions about this are

- `get_main_image_slider_active_picture_src` is too specific. In the next test you want to assert something about the `<img>` itself, so now you make another method, or you refactor everything so that the img element is returned and you do all assertions in the test. But then you want to test the img container, so what is the appropriate level of abstraction?
- Cypress commands are quite expressive by themselves, so do they really need PO abstractions?
- Web page testing is not like component-based frameworks where you can reuse a component in many pages. Generally, one, maybe two, specs cover a web page so PO methods are not very reusable across many pages, e.g your image hero swiper is only going to appear on one page. The exception might be housekeeping stuff like login. You might try to parameterize methods and make them more generic - but the effort seems disproportionate to the reusability gained.
- If your element classes used in selectors are expected to change, use the PO to just return selector strings (which are returned syncronously), e.g

  ```js
  it('tests the picture page for kittens', () => {
    const heroPage = new HeroPage()
    cy.get(heroPage.activeImage)
      .should('have.attr','src')
      .should(src => src.includes('kittens'))              
  })
  ```

You can build up the selectors with string template,

```
this.heroBanner = '.heroBanner'
this.swiper = `${this.herobanner}.swiper-slide`
this.activeSlide = `${this.swiper}.swiper-slide-active`
this.activeImage = `${this.activeSlide} img`
```