# Need to return the response from .then() in cypress

Tags: cypress, pageobjects

I am trying to return the value of .then() and trying to use in another method but I am getting an error and couldn't do that. Please help me with this.

Is there any other way for returning this

```js
test () { 
  var a = cy.request({ 
    method: 'POST', 
    form: true, 
    url: 'https://......../token', 
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, /", "referer-domain": referer_domain, "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8" }, 
    body: { 
      "client_id": "..", 
      "client_secret": "....", 
      "username": username, 
      "password": password, 
      "grant_type": "password", 
      "scope": "" 
    } 
  })
  .then(response => { return response }) 
  return a; 
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cypress: want to define methods as POM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68032266/cypress-want-to-define-methods-as-pom)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return it as a chainable value of the function use [cy.wrap()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wrap#Syntax)

```
cy.get('someElement')
.then(element => {
//some code
return cy.wrap('the value or action I need to retun)
}
.then(returnedValue => {
some code that can use it
}
```

If you want to access it as a variable in the code later you can use [as()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/as)

```
cy.get('someElement')
.then(element => {
//some code
 cy.wrap(result).as('resultAllias')
}

cy.get('@resultAllias')
.then(result => {
//some code to use the result
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this Rosen I tried Wrap but i couldn't get the return but it worked with promise reslove and calling in .then() in it ```login(username, password, referer_domain, jsonPath) {
    return new Cypress.Promise((resolve) => {
        cy.request({
            method: 'POST',
            form: true,
            url: '',
            headers: {
            },
            body: {
            }        
        })
        .then((response) => {
            resolve(response);
        });
    });

    }``` and inside it  it('test', function () {

Comment: Thanks for this Rosen I tried Wrap but i couldn't get the return but it worked with promise reslove and calling in .then() in it ```login() {
    return new Cypress.Promise((resolve) => {
        cy.request({
            method: 'POST',
            form: true,
            url: '',
            headers: {
            },
            body: {
            }        
        })
        .then((response) => {
            resolve(response);
        });
    });

    }``` and inside it  it('test', function () ```helper.login().then((response)=>{})```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but in case anyone comes across this question like I did, the issue is you're writing synchronous code against Cypress functions that are async.

The `.then()` callback attached to your `cy.request()` is going to be executed long after your function already returned, thus it will always result in `var a` being undefined.

The proper way to return the response it to simply return the `cy.request()` function and to use the `.then()` callback in the test to interact with the  response.

```js
test () { 
  // var a = cy.request({
  return cy.request({  
    method: 'POST', 
    form: true, 
    url: 'https://......../token', 
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, /", "referer-domain": referer_domain, "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8" }, 
    body: { 
      "client_id": "..", 
      "client_secret": "....", 
      "username": username, 
      "password": password, 
      "grant_type": "password", 
      "scope": "" 
    } 
  })
  // .then(response => { return response }) 
  // return a; 
}

// Test code
it('works', () => {
  test().then(response => /* utilize the response here */);
});
```